# NextJs credentials Auth with separate backend server and redirection

Tags: reactjs, authentication, next.js

Imagine this scenario, on the `login` page, the user will add their credentials ( username and password ), which will Next `api/login` route, so the api will reply something like `{isAuth: true}` , depending on that the frontend page will receive and ONLY  in that case, it will proceed to the admin panel, otherwise it will redirect to the `login` again.

The purpose is to prevent the disclosure of the admin part of the app to unauthenticated users.

Here is some code where i reach in :

Login page( Front End )

```
 useEffect(() => {
    fetch('api/login')
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => 
        if (data.isAuth) {
          router.push('/admin'); <====== Routing FrontEnd
        }
      });
  }, []);
```

The BackEnd API

```
export default function handler(
  req: NextApiRequest,
  res: NextApiResponse<Data>
) {
  res.status(200).json({ isAuth: true });
}
```

Admin page ( Front end )

```
const Admin: React.FC = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Admin</h1>
    </div>
  );
};

export const getServerSideProps: any = () => {
  return {
    redirect: {
      permanent: false,
      destination: '/login'
    }
  };
};
```

is what I did secure, I mean `router.push` to an admin page that has `getServerSideProps` to check for auth?
`router.push` then  `getServerSideProps` ?

Comment: The redirect from the login page seems fine, but you're currently always redirecting from the admin page too, users will never see that page. Ideally, you'd want to check if users are authenticated in your admin page's `getServerSideProps` as well.

Comment: It’s just a demo code , my question is if i router.push ( client ) then reredirect from getServerSideProps ( server ) will that prevent the disclosure of admin panel?

Comment: If you redirect in `getServerSideProps` users will never get to see the admin page as everything happens on the server-side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes redirecting from `getServerSideProps` will prevent unauthenticated user to reach `admin` route .